# What title do I put on a project where I did the menu, posters, and the art direction of photos but NOT the logo?

Tags: terminology, branding, portfolio

So theres this restaurant that already had a logo. I did their menu, menu board, cards, gift coupons, and posters. I didn't follow any branding guide cause they dont have any. So I started from scratch and just submitted a brief of what colors to use, how photos will be photographed.

Would you say I did the "creative direction" for them? I'm confused to what to put on my portfolio. My title format is "brand name | type of work". What type of work would you say I did? I want to say I did "branding" but I didn't do the logo.

Comment: just a thought... **Miscellaneous Creations**

Comment: I would say that you performed **redesign** work although I don't know how to categorize the items which you produced.

Answer (score 9):

I would use **Brand Collateral** materials.

Meaning you did materials which are collateral with the branding.. but does not indicate you completed the branding itself.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much. But how about the part where I came up with the "style" and the direction of how the photos on the menu and posters will look? I thought of the idea of how its gonna be styled and what colors to use. Can I add that I did the art direction? But I wasnt present while they were shooting the photos.

Comment: Most of the time portfolios aren't *that* descriptive in my experience... that's what the *interview* is for where it can be explained in as much detail as necessary.

Comment: I guess so. But I really just want to put "art direction" somewhere in there cause i enjoy this type of work a lot lol

Comment: Then simply put "Brand collateral and art direction"